# Is android foreground service state affected by blocking notification?

Tags: android

In android as we know there is a feature to block notifications introduced in lollipop on. So if I have a service running as foreground and then user goes and blocks notification of the app, does it affect the foreground state of the service, i,e the service is no longer foreground and more likely to be killed by android.

Answer (score 1):

No.
Blocking notifications only disables the possibility of using `NotificationManager.notify`

Comment: Is this stated somewhere in the docs to establish that service state is unaffected ? because as far as I understand the service foreground status is associated if it is showing a notification or not